# How do you show current tab in javascript for loop and hide all others tabs using ES6

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6, dry

I got the tabs to work but the issue is that I really don't think this follows javascript's don't repeat yourself. As you can see from my code I had to create individual loops for each tab so just that tab would show. The idea is you click the tab and just the description block for that particular tab would show. click tab[0] show just descriptionBlock[0] etc...i also want the initial descriptionBlock to show on pageload. Please no jquery, ES6 javascript is the ideal. Any suggestions would be helpful...

```js
//Product Overview Tabs     
 const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tablist li');
 const descriptionBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.descriptionBlock');
 for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('click', (ev) => { ev.preventDefault(); });
 }

 tabs[0].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[0].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 1; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 
 tabs[1].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[1].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   if (i === 1) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 tabs[2].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[2].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   if (i === 2) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 tabs[3].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[3].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   if (i === 3) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 tabs[4].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[4].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   if (i === 4) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 tabs[5].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[5].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   if (i === 5) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 tabs[6].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[6].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
   if (i === 6) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 } 
 tabs[7].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[7].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   if (i === 7) {
    continue;
   }
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
 tabs[8].onclick = () => {
  descriptionBlock[8].style.display = "block"; 
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="overview-wrapper" id="overview">
  <h2>Pro<span>duct Overv</span>iew</h2>
  <div>
   <div class="product-tabs">
    <div class="miniproduct-wrapper">
     <img src="/_img/models/Model_J.png" alt="Model J" title="Model J" width="150" height="150">
     <h3>Model J6</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="down-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="tablist">
     <li><a href="">Key Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Specifications</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Dimensions</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Product Builder</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Sizing Chart</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Dish Machine<br>Cross Reference<br>Chart</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Options</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Faqs</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="description-tabs">
    <div class="descriptionBlock" style="display:block;">1</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">2</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">3</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">4</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">5</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">6</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">7</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">8</div>
    <div class="descriptionBlock">9</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are correct.  This is certainly not DRY.  For goodness sakes, please use a common shared function rather than copying near-identical code all over the place.  I'd suggest some reading: [DRY principle](https://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-jan-2014/item/1711-lessons-in-good-coding-practices-don-t-repeat-yourself).

Comment: but this doesn't help me adhere to dry... :(

Comment: Come on here.  The advice to use a common function in every one of your click handlers does not give you any idea of what to do?  Create a function that you pass one variable `i` into and call that function from every single click handler.  Do you know how to make a function that takes a parameter and then call it from multiple places?  That's what you do here.  I was trying to get you to figure this out yourself rather than just writing it for you because you will learn more that way.

Comment: i initially had just one loop that I was trying to work with so it would be dry but i had an issue with the other blocks showing so I just wanted to show my working code. I will keep that in mind for future questions. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function `showBlock(index)` that loops over blocks and shows the one with corresponding index. Loop over `tabs` and add event listener that calls `showBlock` with corresponding index. Also you might want to google for `event delegation` to avoid adding multiple event listeners.

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tablist li')
const descriptionBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.descriptionBlock')

const entries = function*(iterable) {
  let i = 0;
  for (item of iterable) {
    yield [i++, item]
  }
}

const showBlock = index => {
  for (const [blockIndex, block] of entries(descriptionBlocks)) {
    block.style.display = blockIndex === index ? 'block' : 'none'
  }
}

showBlock(0)

for (const [tabIndex, tab] of entries(tabs)) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    ev.preventDefault()
    showBlock(tabIndex)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="overview-wrapper" id="overview">
  <h2>Pro<span>duct Overv</span>iew</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="product-tabs">
      <div class="miniproduct-wrapper">
        <img src="/_img/models/Model_J.png" alt="Model J" title="Model J" width="150" height="150">
        <h3>Model J6</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="down-arrow"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="tablist">
        <li><a href="">Key Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dimensions</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product Builder</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sizing Chart</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Dish Machine<br>Cross Reference<br>Chart</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Options</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Faqs</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="description-tabs">
      <div class="descriptionBlock" style="display:block;">1</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">2</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">3</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">4</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">5</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">6</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">7</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">8</div>
      <div class="descriptionBlock">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Yury exactly what I was looking for... Works perfectly. I would suggest adding the ";" after the constant descriptionBlock in case anyone else copies the code and cant figure out why it wont work ;) . Thanks a ton. So much javascript still to learn :)

Comment: The `entries` function is not necessary, it's exactly what [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) does.

Comment: @jstayfaded ASI should insert one for you.

Comment: @MichaelJungo `querySelectorAll` does not return an array. But yes one could convert `NodeList` to array.

Comment: Not sure why a generator is needed here.  A simple common function will work just fine.  Nothing wrong with the generator I guess, but a newbie (which it appears we have here) is more likely to understand just factoring common code into a single function and then calling that from click handlers that are added in a loop.

Comment: Leaving out semicolons to rely on ASI seems like a good way to confuse beginners, especially on SO where random people will pop in here to see questions at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand, just save current selected index and update in click handler:

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tablist li');
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll('.descriptionBlock');
let selectedIndex = 0;

tabs.forEach((tab, i) => {
    // if you really need to do initial "none" assignment in js
    // instead add display none to your css
    descriptions[i].style.display = "none";
    tab.addEventListener('click', (ev) => { 
        ev.preventDefault(); 
        descriptions[selectedIndex].style.display = "none";
        descriptions[i].style.display = "block";
        selectedIndex = i;
    });
});

// select default tab
tabs[selectedIndex].click();
```

Profit!

P.S. You can save whole description block, but if you store index it will be helpful for working with both selected tab and description block.

Comment: I don't think a `nodeList` object which is what `querySelectAll()` returns necessarily has a `.forEach()` method.

Comment: `NodeList` interface has `forEach()` method, proof [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Comment: thanks @Max for your answer. This was easier for me to grasp at this stage of learning.

Comment: Well, there's no `.forEach()` on  a `NodeList` object in Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer.  It is not a feature that is described in a spec.  It is something that Chrome and Firefox have added apparently.  This code does not run in a Microsoft browser and I don't know about Safari.

Comment: And, FYI MDN documents what Firefox does.  You have to read the specification section of MDN (sometimes in detail) to see whether the described behavior is actually standard across many browsers or not or you have to test in modern browsers.  It looks to me like someone is proposing this becomes a standard, but it is not yet such and is not yet universal in modern browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00, yes, you are right, sorry! this `forEach` now is only in draft stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the common code in a function which I will call `showTab()` and then use a loop to add all the click listeners and then just call the common function from each listener:

```
const tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.tablist li'));
const descriptionBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.descriptionBlock');

function showTab(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < descriptionBlock.length; i++) {
        descriptionBlock[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    descriptionBlock[n].style.display = "block"; 
}

for (let [i, tab] of tabs.entries()) {
    tab.addEventListener('click', (ev) => { 
        ev.preventDefault(); 
        showTab(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @jfriend00. I will use this answer as is relatively easier to understand and is compatible with all modern browsers.

Comment: @jstayfaded - Since this appears to the answer you selected, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.